# Creating two WHERE clauses in a MERGE UPDATE in Oracle 11

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have two tables with same structure:
masterTable (id, description, list_price) 
and 
changesTable (id, description, list_price)

I want to merge changes from changesTable into masterTable, but I don't want to update 'description' in masterTable when it is NULL in changesTable, I want to keep old value

I tried to do this

```
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET master.list_price=changes.list_price,
master.description=ch.description   
WHERE length(changes.description)>0
```

but in this case the list_price doesn't get updated as well.

How can I merge them properly?
Thanks

> here is the description of the problem: Use a single merge statement
>   to update the upd_services table with the data in the table
>   upd_services_changes_2. This merge will include updates, deletes and
>   inserts. For this task, a delete is indicated by a negative price in
>   the changes table. If the description field in the changes table is
>   null then do not change the description in the services table when you
>   do the update. Only do an insert if the list price is 0 or greater.

Comment: Also, please specify beforehand when a problem is homework

Comment: You might also want to look into [`nvl`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/nvl.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may try this

```
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET master.list_price=changes.list_price,
master.description = DECODE(ch.description ,
                             NULL,
                             master.description,
                             ch.description )
```

In this case if the ch.description is null then the original value is retained(i.e. master.description) or else ch.description is overwritten on master.description

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

```
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET master.list_price=changes.list_price,
master.description=ch.description   
WHERE length(changes.description)>0
```

This will only update when length(changes.description)>0 but you are intending to say something like 'always update the list_price but only update the list description when it is lenght zero'  You can do this in two merges,

```
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET master.list_price=changes.list_price
```

and

```
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET 
master.description=ch.description   
WHERE length(changes.description)>0
```

or check your [SQL dialect syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606%E2%80%9D) for a way to specify two conditions.

***HINT*** : There is a way to do this, but not with a WHERE statement.  You need to use CASE.  Give it a shot and come back later if you have more questions.

Comment: i have to do it in a single merge statement, using sqlplus v11

Comment: Check out the syntax link, doesn't look possible to specify two columns with different WHERE clauses, not 100% certai nthough

Comment: Do you have to do it with a merge?

Comment: *shrug* check out the syntax in the link, doesn't look possible without some sort of trick.

Comment: here is the description of the problem: Use a single merge statement to update the upd_services table with the data in the table upd_services_changes_2. This merge will include updates, deletes and inserts.
For this task, a delete is indicated by a negative price in the changes table.
If the description field in the changes table is null then do not change the description in the services table when you do the update.
Only do an insert if the list price is 0 or greater.